# Save text field data with Swift 2

Tags: macos, swift2, nstextfield

How can I save text field content with Swift 2.0?

I try to use this:

```
@IBOutlet weak var MyTextField: UITextField! 
@IBOutlet weak var MyLabel: UILabel! 

override func viewDidLoad() { 
    super.viewDidLoad() 
    let stringKey = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults() 
    MyLabel.text = stringKey.stringForKey("savedString­Key") 
} 


@IBAction func saveText(sender: AnyObject) { 
    let myText = MyTextField.text; 
    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().se­tObject(myText, forKey: "savedStringKey") 

    NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().sy­nchronize()
}
```

but Xcode 7 returns an error because I think the code is little bit different from Xcode 6.

[image]

Comment: what error ? can you post error also

Comment: ah, your naming is not obvious! please, rename `stringKey`! Use obvious name as `standardUserDefaults` or `userDefaults` or `defaultsStore` or `defaults`

Comment: In question there is code for UITextField and in photo there is NSTextField. Good going :) What you want? iOS or OS X ?

Comment: i want osx. i'm sorry but i'm new in xcode

Comment: what i have to use for os x programming ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your edit..seems like you are using `NSTextFiled` not `UItextField`..In `NSTextField`, text property doesn't exist ..you need to use `stringValue`

```
myLabel.stringValue = "Your String"
```